# Слово ибо - что означает ?

Tags: значение-слов

что означает слово ибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Употребляется в придаточном предложении причины, соответствует по значению. союзам: **потому что**, **так как**. *Создать язык невозможно, ибо его творит народ.*